Excess amount of SOL being expended from wallet when I swap with Raydium or deposit liquidity into Raydium
This may be a problem that can occur with other Solana programs, but I digress. Whenever I attempt to swap with Raydium, it would appear as if I'm losing more SOL than I should. For example, I might want to swap something for 0.05 SOL, but the total amount of SOL that would be deducted from my wallet would be 0.052, which is a 4% increase. Such a drastic increase should not be possible considering the fees that I am aware of are much lower. As another example, I would deposit 0.004 SOL into a liquidity pool, but the total amount of SOL deducted from my wallet would be 0.02 SOL, which is a whopping 5 times the amount that I should be paying. This is unacceptable, and it would be great if someone had any potential explanations. I do want to note, however, that depositing additional liquidity into an open position does not seem to have the same effect of me overpaying.

This is embarrassing, but I immediately figured out an answer, at least regarding the liquidity pool portion. It turns that there are additional fees with establishing a position. Nevertheless, the best thing to do is to simply not delete the position when withdrawing liquidity so that there are no additional fee costs.

I found that I also encountered the same problem. It should be caused by the transfer between deposit and redemption. In the picture, I have about 0.012sol used as deposit.
But then the amount was not redeemed and the account was closed directly. Can anyone answer my questions? Thanks.

